# why is pylint complaining about missing Exception.message?

Tags: python, exception, pylint

I usually declare a base exception for my modules which does nothing, from that one I derive custom errors that could have additional custom data: AFAIK this is the Right Way™ to use exeptions in Python.

I'm also used to build a human readable message from that custom info and pass it along, so I can refer to that message in error handlers. This is an example:

```
# this code is meant to be compatible with Python-2.7.x

class MycoolmoduleException(Exception):
'''base Mycoolmodule Exception'''

class TooManyFoo(MycoolmoduleException):
'''got too many Foo things'''
def __init__(self, foo_num):
    self.foo_num = foo_num
    msg = "someone passed me %d Foos" % foo_num
    super(TooManyFoo, self).__init__(msg)

# .... somewhere else ....
try:
    do_something()
except Exception as exc:
    tell_user(exc.message)

# real world example using Click
@click.command()
@click.pass_context
def foo(ctx):
    '''do something'''
    try:
        # ... try really hard to do something useful ...
    except MycoolmoduleException as exc:
        click.echo(exc.message, err=True)
        ctx.exit(-1)
```

Now, when I run that code through `pylint-2.3.1` it complains about my use of `MycoolmoduleException.message`:

```
coolmodule.py:458:19: E1101: Instance of 'MycoolmoduleException' has no 'message' member (no-member)
```

That kind of code always worked for me (both in Python2 and Python3) and `hasattr(exc, 'message')` in the same code returns `True`, so why is pylint complaining? And/or: how could that code be improved?

(NB the same happens if I try to catch the built in `Exception` instead of my own `MycoolmoduleException`)